# SSAS: Processing Dimension without affecting the published cube?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, sql-server-2016, dimensions

Every day, I process the DimDate dimension before processing the cube. If I process the cube without processing the dimension, it's very likely the cube will generate date errors.

Regardless of how I process the dimension (`ProcessFull` or `ProcessData`) the cube becomes unavailable in Excel or PowerBi.

On the other hand, if I process the cube without `ProcessData`, the cube will be available in the server while it's being processed.

How can I process a Dimension without affecting the usability of the cube?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ProcessUpdate for dimensions and ProcessFull/ProcessData for the cube (potentially individual measure groups and/or individual partitions depending on the amount of you fact data).
It's still a good practice to run ProcessFull also for dimensions from time to time (for example, on a weekend or once a month), because ProcessUpdate makes soft (logical) deletes on the dimension members which don't exist anymore which will make your dimensions larger with the time.
Also please checkout the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/processing-options-and-settings-analysis-services?view=sql-analysis-services-2022)